# How to apply CSS style changes if I'm either on one of the two pages?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Each of my page has unique class in the body tag. Editing elements if I hit desired page works fine with the following:

```
.page1 .someClass p{
    color: #cccccc
}
```

How do I achieve same effect with color change if I hit another page, as my body class would turn to page2 instead of page1 => `<body class="page2">`?

Also, this effect would occur only if I'm either on page1 or page2, not on any other pages whatsoever, but keep in mind that all other pages do have same body class like these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the same eclass in both pages but NOT in the other ones, then you have to duplicate the rule:

```
.page1 .someClass p, .page2 .someClass p { background: red }
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. So, even later on if I go further more to apply css rules from one file to let's say 50 pages, I'd have to duplicate these rules all the time? Isn't there some nicer way like [.page1 || .page2 || .page3] .someClass p { background: red } (I'm just writing it down so you get the idea).

Comment: you can use a general rule something like `.someClass p {}` which has the properties for all the pages and then specify for each page(s) something like in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try an attribute selector with a substring. For instance:

```
body[class^="page"]
```

This selector targets all `body` elements that have an attribute `class`, who's value *begins with* `page`.

Although this may not be what you're asking in your question, as I'm not entirely sure what you meant in the last part.

More here: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-substrings